# How do I continiously deploy my latest NodeJS/TypeScript branch commit to a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, git, gitlab

I have a Windows machine, that is supposed to continously pull the latest commit from a specific GitLab branch, and build and deploy the commit.
Basically, I want something like Heroku, but self-hosted on a Windows machine.

I tried looking into AppVeyor and Jenkins, but am unsure what to use to acquire the just-mentioned requirements. I get the basics of git, but have no idea how to deploy the application now it is finished. I'm sorry if the question is not specific or detailed enough.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have any sample code to show? Otherwise, I think you're right that you're not being specific enough. This question is asking someone to write your code for you, which will get you some down-votes.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Gitlab-Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) on a Windows machine and configure it to automatically build & deploy the latest changes.

Comment: I was looking for something like that. The documentation is just too large for me to understand.